# Lógica para crear Json-LD breadcrumbs de forma dinamica - Javascript

Tags: javascript

No se muy bien que titulo ponerle a la pregunta, ya que estoy trabajando con Json-ld breadcrumbs y quiero hacer una parte dinamica, para lo cual necesitaria crear una funcion javascript y no se me caen muchas ideas.

Basicamente, si estoy parado en `localhost:3000/page1/page2` me llega un slug del tipo `page1/page2`, el cual convierto en la variable `const segments = slug.split("/");`. Segments ahora es un array que contiene `['page1','page2']`

Actualmente, tengo esta funcion

```
${segments.map((segment, index) => {
    const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : `${baseURL}/${segments[index - 1]}/${segment}`;
    return `
      {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": ${index + 2},
          "item": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "@id": "${url}",
            "name": "${capitalizeEachWord(segment.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " "))}",
            "image": ""
          }}`;
})}
```

Y esta funcion me retorna diferentes Schemas, uno para `localhost:3000/page1`, y otro para `localhost:3000/page1/page2`.

Ahora, si yo entro al sitio `localhost:3000/page1/page2/page3`, esta logica ya no me sirve

```
const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : `${baseURL}/${segments[index - 1]}/${segment}`;
```

ya que el ultimo schema, deberia ser `localhost:3000/page1/page2/page3`, y en su lugar es `localhost:3000/page2/page3`

Yo deberia reemplazar esa logica por algo como

```
const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : myFunction(segments, index);
```

o similar, es decir, crear una funcion que me devuelva, por cada elemento en el array `segments`, la cantidad de schemas correspondientes, con sus valores correspondientes. Pero no me doy cuenta como hacer esta funcion. Alguna sugerencia o idea? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función quedaría así:

```
function myFunction(segments, index) {
   return segments.slice(0,1+index).join('/');
}
```

y la llamas:

```
const url = `${baseURL}/${myFunction(segments,index)}`;
```

Comment: cuando lo ves resuelto era tan simple... llevo casi 3 horas buscando que a mi cerebro le salga esta funcion y no se me caia una idea. Gracias crack de crackens.

Comment: De nada, me alegro haber podido ayudar